# aligning dynamically generated elements using css

Tags: css

Hello guys i have a small problem with my elements. I am getting this elements dynamically and i want to present them as a 4 columns layout. the problem that i can't wrap them between and div and just do display inline block and float left because they are coming like that separate.

```
<section data-field="box-image">
    <img
        src=""
        width="160" height="160" alt="">
</section>
<section data-field="box-content">
    <h3>Aquarius</h3>
    <p>20 January&nbsp;- 18 February</p>

</section>
<section data-field="box-image">
    <img
        src=""
        width="160" height="160" alt="">
</section>
<section data-field="box-content">
    <h3>Pisces</h3>
    <p>19 February&nbsp;- 20 March</p>
</section>
```

so it shows like that : 
[image]

**but what i want is to show them like that:**
[image]

i actually thought about wrapping them using jquery or javascript but can i do this using css ?

this is how this html is being generated to me on the DOM:
{{#each infoContent as |item|}}

```
 <div class="col-md-12 boxes-container">

                    {{{item.box}}}


                </div>

                {{/each}}
```

so this item.box generate the code i am asking about.

simple i want to wrap each box-image and  box-content in a div so i can put some css on them or if there any other way to present them like in my image would be really nice to read it.

Comment: {{#each infoContent as |item|}}

                    <div class="col-md-12 boxes-container">

                        {{{item.box}}}


                    </div>

                    {{/each}} . this generate the html i dont have css on it

Comment: what is creating the code for `item.box`, can you not change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code**

using `position` and `flex`

```css
section:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    left: 0;
    width:160px;
}
.section-block {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
section:nth-child(4) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    right: 0;
    width:160px;
}
section:nth-child(1) {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-block">

<section data-field="box-image">
    <img
        src=""
        width="160" height="160" alt="">
</section>
<section data-field="box-content">
    <h3>Aquarius</h3>
    <p>20 January&nbsp;- 18 February</p>

</section>
<section data-field="box-image">
    <img
        src=""
        width="160" height="160" alt="">
</section>
<section data-field="box-content">
    <h3>Pisces</h3>
    <p>19 February&nbsp;- 20 March</p>
</section>

</div>
```

using `Flexbox Columns`

```css
section {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    text-align: center;
}
.section-block {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 320px;
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
section:nth-child(1) {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-block">

<section data-field="box-image">
    <img
        src=""
        width="160" height="160" alt="">
</section>
<section data-field="box-content">
    <h3>Aquarius</h3>
    <p>20 January&nbsp;- 18 February</p>

</section>
<section data-field="box-image">
    <img
        src=""
        width="160" height="160" alt="">
</section>
<section data-field="box-content">
    <h3>Pisces</h3>
    <p>19 February&nbsp;- 20 March</p>
</section>

</div>
```

using `column-count`

```css
section {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.section-block {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px; 
    -moz-column-gap: 40px; 
    column-gap: 40px;
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-block">

<section data-field="box-image">
    <img
        src=""
        width="160" height="160" alt="">
</section>
<section data-field="box-content">
    <h3>Aquarius</h3>
    <p>20 January&nbsp;- 18 February</p>

</section>
<section data-field="box-image">
    <img
        src=""
        width="160" height="160" alt="">
</section>
<section data-field="box-content">
    <h3>Pisces</h3>
    <p>19 February&nbsp;- 20 March</p>
</section>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapped the image and text with a `div`.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section data-field="box-image">
    <img src="" width="160" height="160" alt="">
  </section>
  <section data-field="box-content">
    <h3>Aquarius</h3>
    <p>20 January&nbsp;- 18 February</p>

  </section>
</div>
<div>
  <section data-field="box-image">
    <img src="" width="160" height="160" alt="">
  </section>
  <section data-field="box-content">
    <h3>Pisces</h3>
    <p>19 February&nbsp;- 20 March</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: hey thank you so much for your answer. my problem is that i can't wrap them between a div bec they come dynamically. i do understand this idea but this is not what i want.

Comment: I dont think this can be done without wrapping in an element.

Comment: why add the div, why not just apply the style directly to the section tag?

Comment: it won't work and because the code get generated for me like that `<div class="col-md-12 boxes-container">

                    {{{item.box}}}


                </div>

                {{/each}}` . item.box generate the code for me

Comment: @Pete The image is wrapped in one section and the text in another section. There is no element which wraps both together.

Comment: haha, didn't see that - that's just bad structure and semantically incorrect

Comment: its really annoying i see :( i dunno what to do actually